# Denie user-Access for directory WinSrv2012r2

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying with no results, I searched the inet with the same results of my tryings! So may i'll get some help here :D

**Windows Server 2012 R2**

**Directorys:**

```
C:\...
D:\aaa\...
D:\bbb\...
D:\ccc\...
```

**Users:**

```
User1  (Groups: Users)
User2  (Groups: Users)
User3  (Groups: Users)
User4  (Groups: Users)
```

**Task:**

I want to denie ***User4*** from accessing `D:\bbb\...`

The folder gives `Users` the right to access it.

**How can I achive this?**

I tried to add user4 to the folder and take rights. but since user4 is in group users (what he has to be) he gets erased after sage because he allredy grands access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from the Folder - Properties - Security section.

Simply "Edit" the permission, and then "Add" User4 specifically, and then choose `Deny` on full control.

"Deny" permission is always get first priority and if anyone has "Deny" attached to them, it will get applied first (Even if they Inherited access from the above folder, the Deny will apply).

If you still want User4 to SEE the content but no write access, then simply "Deny" write. If you don't want any access at all, then use "Deny" on all.